# How to style chat window using CSS when using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, css, azure, bots, botframework

I have created a simple Chat bot through the use of Microsoft Q&A maker and deployment to azure. Out of the box, the bot has its own default style.

I want to be able to edit the look and feel of the chat window, possibly using CSS. I have found a couple of questions here but they do not give the complete answer I am looking for. I have done some research and found information at these URLs:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/202

The first link above gives this explanation under the heading of 'Styling':

"In the  `/src/scss/`  folder you will find the source files for generating  `/botchat.css` . Run  npm run build-css  to compile once you've made your changes. For basic branding, change  `colors.scss`  to match your color scheme. For advanced styling, change  `botchat.scss` ."

I do not fully understand how these files are connected to my project. I also do not know how to implement the techniques outlined above. I cannot find a specific set of steps to take to change the style of the chat window. Hopefully someone can explain in detail how I can use the techniques above (or that they know already) to change my bot styles.

If anyone knows the most straight forward method to style the Microsoft Bot chat window, or could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How is it working now?

`I do not fully understand how these files are connected to my project`: assuming that you are using `iframe` implementation, it means that you are using the compiled version of the source code you found.

If you have a look to the `iframe` content (doing a GET on the URL), it looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>MyBotId</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
        <link href="/css/adaptive/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="/css/adaptive/botchat-fullwindow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="BotChatElement"></div>
        <script src="/scripts/adaptive/botchat.js"></script>
        <script>
            var model = {
                 "userId": "demo1234",
                 "userName": "You",
                 "botId": "MyBotId",
                 "botIconUrl": "//bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default-8.png",
                 "botName": "MyBotId",
                 "secret": "mySecret",
                 "iconUrl": "//bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default-8.png",
                 "directLineUrl": "https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline",
                 "webSocketEnabled": "false"
            };
        </script>
        <script>
        BotChat.App({
            directLine: {
                secret: model.secret,
                token: model.token,
                domain: model.directLineUrl,
                webSocket: false
            },
            user: { id: model.userId, name: model.userName },
            bot: { id: model.botId, name: model.botName },
            resize: 'window'
        }, document.getElementById("BotChatElement"));

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So as you can see, it is referencing a **css file**, the one compiled by the GitHub project.

---

### How to add your custom css?

On your side, you can edit this css, edit it, and use the same implementation as above but replace the css link to yours.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still having difficulty changing the chat window styles. From what you said it seems possible to use my own custom styles and save them. Then replace the css link code. Although the problem is that I do not know how to edit the HTML file you gave above and add my own custom css. As I am unsure to where it comes from?

Comment: You just have to create your own HTML file taking the same structure. Or if your web chat is included in a page, add the style, link and scripts parts

Comment: Great stuff. I can now style the bot as I want to. One problem now though is that the Bot is not functioning correctly? When I type in a message to send I cannot actually submit the text. Any idea of why this would occur / a fix for the problem?

Comment: As I don't know what you exactly did, it's difficult to got an idea of the problem

Comment: I got the relevant HTML for my bot (helped by the section of code you gave in your answer). I then saved this locally in its own file and referred to this file in and `<iframe>` tag. I can edit the colors / styles etc. But I am now unable to submit and received messages. I guess its something to do with the original HTML that I have (similar to you answer above). But I made no changes to my own after the GET. Would you have any ideas as to what I could do? PS - really appreciate the help so far!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149623/discussion-between-user3573796-and-nicolas-r).

Comment: Got it sorted, my file path to the `botchat.js` file was incorrect. With Nicolas' help I can now style the chat window how I want and embed it into my web page. Thanks a lot Nicolas!

Answer (score 2):

To customize the WebChat module, head on over to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat and fork the repository, then you can add your own CSS customizations and deploy your own custom themed chat interface.  You will find the styling options here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/src/scss

### Customizing WebChat

#### Styling

In the `/src/scss/` folder you will find the source files for generating `/botchat.css`. Run `npm run build-css` to compile once you've made your changes. For basic branding, change `colors.scss` to match your color scheme. For advanced styling, change `botchat.scss`.

Card Sizes / Responsiveness

WebChat strives to use responsive design when possible. As part of this, WebChat cards come in 3 sizes: narrow (216px), normal (320px) and wide (416px). In a full-window chat, these sizes are invoked by a CSS media query in the `/botchat-fullwindow.css` style sheet. You may customize this style sheet for the media query breakpoints in your own application. Or, if your WebChat implementation is not a full-window experience, you can manually invoke card sizes by adding the CSS classes `wc-narrow` and `wc-wide` to the HTML element containing your chat.

#### Strings

You can alter or add localized strings in `/src/Strings.ts`:

- Add one or more locales (with associated localized strings) to `localizedStrings`
- Add logic to map the requested locale to the supported locale in `strings`
- Please help the community by submitting a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pulls).

#### Behaviors

Behavioral customization will require changing the TypeScript files in `/src`. A full description of the architecture of WebChat is beyond the scope of this document, but here are a few starters:

#### Architecture

- `Chat` is the top-level React component
- `App` creates a React application consists solely of `Chat`
- `Chat` largely follows the Redux architecture laid out in [this video series](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree)
- To handle async side effects of Redux actions, `Chat` uses `Epic` from [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org) - here's a [video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sF5-V-Szo0c)
- Underlying `redux-observable` (and also [DirectLineJS](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-directlinejs)) is the `RxJS` library, which implements the Observable pattern for wrangling async. A minimal grasp of `RxJS` is key to understanding WebChat's plumbing.

### Building WebChat

1. Clone (or fork) this repo
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run build` (to build on every change `npm run watch`, to build production `npm run prepublish`)

This builds the following:

- `/built/*.js` compiled from the TypeScript sources in `/src/*.js` - `/built/BotChat.js` is the root
- `/built/*.d.ts` declarations for TypeScript users - `/built/BotChat.d.ts` is the root
- `/built/*.js.map` sourcemaps for easier debugging
- `/botchat.js` webpacked UMD file containing all dependencies (React, Redux, RxJS, polyfills, etc.)
- `/botchat.css` base stylesheet
- `/botchat-fullwindow.css` media query stylesheet for a full-window experience